# Android on click the item menu is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

Here is the code in my fragment

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("aaa", "ee");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            Log.e("sssssss","SSSSSSSSSSSSSSs");
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    EditCustomerProfile.class);
            //startActivityForResult(editIntent, EditProfile);
            startActivity(editIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**I can see the menu item in my action bar.**

I inflate the menu like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        int currentTab = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentTab == 1) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_addresses, menu);
        } else if (currentTab == 0) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**I am talking about profile menu**

but when i click on the edit, nothing happened, even the log is not working

Comment: why the -1 ? i had a problem, i tried to solve it but i couldn't.

Comment: @blackbelt Fragment from the support v4, it is really weird, i have like millions of fragments on my program, and each one have menu, i don't know why this one doesn't work

Comment: so onOptionsItemSelected is not called? Do you have onOptionsItemSelected inside the activity?

Comment: @blackbelt yes it is not called, the log is not being printed in the logcat, weird right?

Comment: a little bit. Did you override the same method inside the activity that host the fragment?

Comment: @blackbelt no of course. the `ProfileTabs`, which has the `on prepare `, host the `CustomerProfileNew`, which has the `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: the naming convention is a bit confusing. is `ProfileTabs`   the Activity and  `CustomerProfileNew` is the fragment? It seems strange to me but without having the whole picture is kind of impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: @blackbelt yes the profileTabs is the activity and the customerProfileNew is the fragment, the profileTabs has two tabs in the action bar, the first one is the customerprofileNew. also, i am using viewpager to move between tabs. is it clear now?

Comment: Have you called `hasOptionsMenu(true)` in the respective fragment's `onCreate()`?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma yes that is the solution, i already found it thanks :)

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so that others can learn from this exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're creating your menu through your activity, but are trying to intercept menu item selection in your fragment.

In order for the fragment to be included in the call stack of `onOptionItemSelected()`, you should make ensure that the fragment has called `hasOptionsMenu(true)` in its respective `onCreate()`.